# mailto on submit validation error

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using jquery validate.
I'm fairly certain that theres a sequence issue here.

Here's what is going on.

I have a mailto link that's NOT an  submit button, but is an anchor tag instead because I need the mailto attribute.

The mailto: is being populated using JS.

The problem is when I click the button to submit, my $("form").submit() is happening, validation is happening as well, but then it continues to open the mailto: attribute. Which I don't want if there are fields that aren't populated.

I understand this is because on the click event the mailto has nothing stopping it from continuing onto the next line of code. How can I say on submit, if validation has errors, don't run the next bit of code. But if it does not have errors, run the next bit of code.

Some code is left out since it's not important, but here's my code.

```
</section>
<!-- end feedback -->
<div class="email">
    Enter your email:
    <input type="email" size="50" placeholder="example@example.com" name="email" class="email-value" required>
</div>

<a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg m-0a mb-5 mt-3 cursor-pointer email-link">Email Results</a>
```

and the js...

```
$("form").validate({
        "rules": {
            "question-1": "required",
            "question-2": "required",
            "question-3a": "required",
            "question-3b": "required",
            "question-3c": "required",
            "question-4": "required",
            "question-5": "required",
            "question-6": "required",
            "question-7": "required",
            "email": {
                "required": true
            }
        },
        "messages": {
            "question-1": "Required",
            "question-2": "Required",
            "question-3a": "Required",
            "question-3b": "Required",
            "question-3c": "Required",
            "question-4": "Required",
            "question-5": "Required",
            "question-6": "Required",
            "question-7": "Required",
            "email": "Email is required to send the results."
        }
    });

    $(".email-link").on("click", function(e) {  
            $("form").submit()
            //THIS IS WHERE I THINK I NEED TO STOP THE QUERY FROM EXECUTING UNTIL VALIDATION IS FINE.
            var emailAddress = $("input[name=email]").val();
            var subject = "How%20Asthma%20Friendly%20Is%20Your%20School?";
            var response = "Thanks%20for%20completing%20the%20American%20Lung%20Association%20Assessment%2C%20How%20Asthma%20Friendly%20Is%20Your%20School%3F%20%0AYour%20answers%3A" +
            "%20%0AQuestion%201%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-1]:checked").val() + 
            "%20%0AQuestion%202%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-2]:checked").val() + 
            "%20%0AQuestion%203a%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-3a]:checked").val() + 
            "%20%0AQuestion%203b%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-3b]:checked").val() + 
            "%20%0AQuestion%203c%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-3c]:checked").val() + 
            "%20%0AQuestion%202%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-4]:checked").val() +
            "%20%0AQuestion%202%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-5]:checked").val() +
            "%20%0AQuestion%202%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-6]:checked").val() +
            "%20%0AQuestion%202%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-7]:checked").val();

            $(this).attr({
                href: "mailto:" + emailAddress + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + response
            });
    });
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across the same problem. This is the solution.

```
var = validlate = $("form").validate({
        "rules": {
            "question-1": "required",
            "question-2": "required",
            "question-3a": "required",
            "question-3b": "required",
            "question-3c": "required",
            "question-4": "required",
            "question-5": "required",
            "question-6": "required",
            "question-7": "required",
            "email": {
                "required": true
            }
        },
        "messages": {
            "question-1": "Required",
            "question-2": "Required",
            "question-3a": "Required",
            "question-3b": "Required",
            "question-3c": "Required",
            "question-4": "Required",
            "question-5": "Required",
            "question-6": "Required",
            "question-7": "Required",
            "email": "Email is required to send the results."
        }
    });

$(".email-link").on("click", function(e) {
        if ( validator.form() ) {
            var emailAddress = $("input[name=email]").val();
            var subject = "How%20Asthma%20Friendly%20Is%20Your%20School?";
            var response = "Thanks%20for%20completing%20the%20American%20Lung%20Association%20Assessment%2C%20How%20Asthma%20Friendly%20Is%20Your%20School%3F%20%0AYour%20answers%3A" +
            "%20%0AQuestion%201%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-1]:checked").val() + 
            "%20%0AQuestion%202%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-2]:checked").val() + 
            "%20%0AQuestion%203a%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-3a]:checked").val() + 
            "%20%0AQuestion%203b%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-3b]:checked").val() + 
            "%20%0AQuestion%203c%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-3c]:checked").val() + 
            "%20%0AQuestion%202%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-4]:checked").val() +
            "%20%0AQuestion%202%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-5]:checked").val() +
            "%20%0AQuestion%202%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-6]:checked").val() +
            "%20%0AQuestion%202%3A%20" + $("input[name=question-7]:checked").val();

            $(this).attr({
                href: "mailto:" + emailAddress + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + response
            });
        } else {
            alert("Missing required field");
            return false;
        }
    });
```